# Aria2c Inactive torrents blocks the upstream queue

Tags: bittorrent, aria2

Lets suppose I have 10 torrents added to the aria2c & I have set a maximum of 2 simultaneous downloads. When queue starts 2 will be in the progress & 8 will be in queue.

Due to reason such as low seeds/peers 1st torrent becomes totally CLOGGED say at 12% & the 2nd active torrent too face the same result I will have a queue of 8 torrents remaining unprocessed TILL further human input.

How can I solve this pseudo-inactive torrents?

Comment: Increase the number of max downloads?

Comment: Thats lame don't u think?

Comment: It's a valid solution to your issue. The 10 torrents will download in parallel. The ones with more seeds will download faster ...